# Compound query in django -- use extra, annotate, or raw sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I need to do the following query:

```
open_positions = Jobs.objects.all()
open_positions_with_apply = open_positions.extra(`has_applied` = 
            JobApplication.objects.filter(profile=profile, job=job).exists()
```

To clarify what I want to do:

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=1)
new_query_set = []
for job in Jobs.objects.all():
    has_applied = JobApplication.objects.filter(job=job, profile=profile)
    new_query_set.append(job with its has_applied value) # in pseudocode, not sure how this would be done
```

Basically given a profile (the user visiting the page), and a QuerySet of jobs, I need to find a boolean of whether the user has applied. How would I do this with a django query?

Comment: You've tried to filter on `has_applied=True` already?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I went about solving this by getting a `job_id` values_list of the jobs the user has applied for, and in the template -

```
{% for job in jobs %}
    {% if job.id not in jobs_user_has_applied_to %}
    <form>...
    {% else %}
    You've applied for this
{% endfor %}
```